# The 'terminal-plus' package for Atom editor doesn't work

Tags: editor, atom

I am using Atom editor on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit and I installed terminal-plus package.
I can create a new terminal but I cannot write into it as you see in the screenshot below

[image]

PS: I don't know if it's related to this error:
[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null](https://github.com/jeremyramin/terminal-plus/issues/277)  which I have.

Comment: The `terminal-plus` package hasn't been updated for a while though. I suspect this is a bug with the package and is probably not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I used to use it but not anymore. AFAIK, there are similar packages that are still updated, so you should do a search.

Comment: I have developed an Atom package that serves as a maintained substitute for `terminal-plus`: `terminal-fusion`. It has a few extra themes and features.

Comment: Link to a possible fix: https://github.com/jeremyramin/terminal-plus/issues/321#issuecomment-242193432 Basically; a dependency a few packages deep is outdated.

Comment: @BrentonHorne: Nice. Would you mind posting an answer with the installation procedure? Notify me through a comment if you want my up-vote on it! In the mean time for everybody else: https://atom.io/packages/terminal-fusion

Comment: This package has issue while installing. I was unable to make it work and ended up switching to **"platformio-ide-terminal"** it can be customized too

Answer (score 10):

The `terminal-plus` package is unmaintained with its last update being in November 2015. So I would like to advise that you switch to my Atom package (please note, that this package is only compatible with Linux platforms, if you want a terminal package to use on your non-Linux machines please use [`platformio-ide-terminal`](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) instead!), [`terminal-fusion`](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-fusion). To install it merely run:

```
$ apm install terminal-fusion --no-confirm
```

where `$` denotes a user console (so do **not** run this command as root!). I would advise that you uninstall `terminal-plus` first via running:

```
$ apm remove terminal-plus --no-confirm
```

If you would like to show your appreciation for my package, please star it with `apm`, by running:

```
$ apm star terminal-fusion
```

or star it on GitHub by logging into GitHub and clicking "Star" at the URL https://github.com/fusion809/terminal-fusion.

EDIT: This answer is now out-of-date I'm afraid as terminal-fusion is no longer maintained so please use platformio-ide-terminal instead. To install it run:

```
$ apm install platformio-ide-terminal --no-confirm
```

where is `$` is the user console. To star it and thereby show your appreciation to its author (which isn't me, but they still deserve your appreciation) run:

```
$ apm star platformio-ide-terminal
```

Comment: Please consider accepting and potentially upvoting this answer if you like it.

Comment: Thank you Brenton. Started using platformio-ide-terminal on my Mac! (: